# What's the difference between an inner product and an inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I was wondering what the precise definition between these two is. I understand what the inner product is, and its geometric interpretation. Is the inner product **space** just a vector space that contains all these inner product vectors?

I'm a little confused and would like some guidance.

Comment: Yes, an inner product space is simply a vector space equipped with an inner product.

Comment: There is no inner product vector. An inner product takes two vectors and outputs a scalar. It is an operation you define on a space of vectors so that you can talk about orthogonality. It also induces a norm on the space so you can talk about modulus and distance.